# Guidance on how to make a theming mechanism that effects all components in Angular?

Tags: angular, redux, themes, ngrx, global-state

### **Question:**

I need guidance on how to write a mechanism in Angular to set the "Look and Feel" of components globally in my application. Please note, I'm trying to learn [@ngrx/platform](https://github.com/ngrx/platform) and I thought this would be an interesting design constraint; however, I'm willing to let it go if it just doesn't make sense.

**Breakdown:**

I have an application in progress with many components.  Each component in my application has currently 3 possible "look and feels(L&F)":

- Morning (sepia)
- Afternoon (white)
- Evening (dark)

*Please note there could be a spectrum of colors based on more granular time*.

These L&Fs are set by the time of day of the current user e.g if user current time is 7 AM, the calculated L&F would be set to "Morning".  I'm tracking this state inside [ngrx/store](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/README.md) of an angular module called `SundialModule` and `gnomon` is the mechanism of reducers and actions for `getting` or `setting` state:

**sundial/reducers/gnomon.ts:**

```
import * as gnomon from '../actions';

export interface State {
  currentHour: number,
}

const initialState: State = {
  currentHour: new Date().getHours()
};

export function reducer(state = initialState,
                        action: gnomon.Actions) {
  console.log(action, 'action');
    switch(action.type) {
      case gnomon.MORNING:
        return  {
          ...state,
          currentHour: 6,
        };
      case gnomon.AFTERNOON:
        return  {
          ...state,
          currentHour: 12,
        };
      case gnomon.EVENING:
        return  {
          ...state,
          currentHour: 7,
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

Now I have an [Angular Attribute directive](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) called `[sundialTheme]` that will set a [`HostBinding('class') theme = 'light'`](https://angular.io/api/core/HostBinding) on the element it's placed upon.

**sundial/directives/theme.ts**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[sundialTheme]'
})
export class SundialThemeDirective implements OnInit {
  @HostBinding('class') theme = 'light';

  private gnomon: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private store: Store<fromGnomon.State>) {
    this.gnomon = store.select<any>('gnomon');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.gnomon.subscribe((theme) => {
      if(theme.currentHour >= 7 && theme.currentHour <= 11){
        this.theme = 'sepia';
      } else if( theme.currentHour >= 12 && theme.currentHour <= 18) {
        this.theme = 'light'
      } else {
        this.theme = 'dark'
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**The problem:** Every component in my application will need to have this attribute of `sundialTheme`; moreover, every component will have a subscription to the `this.gnomon = store.select<any>('gnomon');`, which feels expensive/heavyhanded. Lastly, and as an aside gripe, is that, every component will need to have my `sundialModule` injected at every feature module, and every component will need the set of themes for each Time of day:

An example of this, every template's component.
*note: `sundialTheme` attribute directive:*

```
<mh-pagination sundialTheme></mh-pagination>
<canvas glBootstrap class="full-bleed" sundialTheme></canvas>
<running-head [state]="(state$ | async)" sundialTheme></running-head>
<menu-navigation sundialTheme></menu-navigation>
<folio sundialTheme></folio>
<mh-footer sundialTheme></mh-footer>
```

Every Feature Module with a `SundialModule` dependency:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SundialModule
  ],
})
export class MenuModule {
}
```

Every component styleUrls with `sundial-links`:
*note the ugly sundial-morning.scss*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'running-head',
  templateUrl: 'running-head.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    'running-head.component.scss',
    '../../../components/sundial/sundial-morning.scss', // This !
  ],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class RunningHeadComponent {
}
```

Finally I've had other ways offered to me:

1) Since I'm using Angular CLI, I could add my styles globally and have a directive set a class on the body.  Which seems to break any kind of web component standards.

2) I could use a factory loader in each components `styleUrls:[]`; which I havent gotten clarity on how to implement.

3) I could follow material design components architecture which adds the themes directly into the components which doesn't feel very dry? (however, I havent researched too deeply into)

4) I could make a custom decorator for each component (could be viable but I'm nto sure how to implement)

Any other suggestions? Any best practices with reasoning?

Comment: I think you should just use themes (from material for example). You set a class at the top of your app and you just define all your components according to that.

Comment: Is there something that prevents you from inheriting SundialThemeDirective in all themed components?

Comment: @estus I mean it just doesn't feel like is a "is a" relationships also,   The community is saying use a factory loader or right your own decorators.  Which I have no idea how to do either

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Class inheritance is exactly a relationship here. Because all descendant components should inherit common behaviour from a parent. I cannot confirm if this will surely work as expected because I don't do ngrx. I'm not sure which community you're referring to, but class decorator doesn't fit here because of its limitations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@HostBinding('class') theme = 'light'
```

should better be

```
@HostBinding('class.light') isLight = theme === 'light';
```

to not overwriting all other classes on this element.

You can set the class only in AppComponent and use in component styles

```
:host-context(.light) {
  // my light component styles here
}
```

Comment: 1) thanks for the correction on Hostbinders.
2) https://alligator.io/angular/styles-between-components-angular/ well I'll be damned that missing piece of the puzzle with :host-context.

QQ: I was also told that I could use a factory loader in the styleUrl of the component does that mean anything to you? Or another offering was a custom decorator*. Would love to hear alternatives ideas?  Or how I'm doing it is how you would more or less do it? regardless, marking correct.

Comment: I don't know about factory-loader. I'd just use host-context. It's CSS only. All other options seem too complicated to me.